# Question title missing

Tags: support, titles

So this came up on the main page

[image]

The second question has **no title** apparently. Clicking on "Awesome"'s username takes me to the user page, where I see the same thing.

[image: image2]

Is this a bug? Also apparently since it has $4$ page views, I would guess that some people can in fact click on the link. (I can't, not even on the `...`)

Comment: It seems the user intentionally created a question with title containing only soft-hypen (unicode 173). The system don't know how to generate a clickable link for this. I can only get in by "view-source" and type the URL in the address bar.

Comment: @achillehui so much like this profile picture he is trolling?

Comment: it is possible the user is trolling or the account get hacked. In any event, the URL of the question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716639/ I have casted a vote to delete it.

Comment: @achillehui it is on hold now. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716639/

Comment: maybe because of this post?

Comment: Tis now deleted.

Comment: aw yiss.${}{}{}$